# Extracting data with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, linux, bash, xmlstarlet

I want to extract the content of a .xml file using xmlstarlet, and write it to a variable.

The .xml file is the output from mediainfo, and for example I want to extract the frame rate from Video, the problem is the tags (`<BitRate>`) named the same, the only difference is the `<track type="Video"></track>` around it.

I want to avoid the regular expression method with `sed` because I think a program is better and easier to handle. And I want to avoid something like take the 2nd BitRate entry. Its not the first and surely not the last xml operation in the Bash script.

The insertion of information works very good with (for example):

```
xmlstarlet -q ed -L -P -u "/movie1/videoframerate" -v "123456 Kb/s" ./test.xml
```

This is a typical XML output from mediainfo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MediaInfo xmlns="https://mediaarea.net/mediainfo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://mediaarea.net/mediainfo https://mediaarea.net/mediainfo/mediainfo_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
<creatingLibrary version="17.12" url="https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfo">MediaInfoLib</creatingLibrary>
<media ref="/path/to/file.mkv">

<track type="General">
 <UniqueID>174213452352936523294326454020021161878</UniqueID>
 <VideoCount>1</VideoCount>
 <AudioCount>2</AudioCount>
 <FileExtension>mkv</FileExtension>
 <Format>Matroska</Format>
 <Format_Version>2</Format_Version>
 <FileSize>7655754558</FileSize>
 <Duration>7087.808</Duration>
 <OverallBitRate>8641041</OverallBitRate>
 <FrameRate>23.976</FrameRate>
 <FrameCount>169937</FrameCount>
 <StreamSize>152359808</StreamSize>
 <IsStreamable>Yes</IsStreamable>
 <Encoded_Date>UTC 2010-09-04 22:54:43</Encoded_Date>
 <File_Modified_Date>UTC 2010-09-07 07:56:15</File_Modified_Date>
 <File_Modified_Date_Local>2010-09-07 07:56:15</File_Modified_Date_Local>
 <Encoded_Application>mkvmerge v3.3.0 (&apos;Language&apos;) built on Mar 24 2010 14:59:24</Encoded_Application>
 <Encoded_Library>libebml v0.8.0 + libmatroska v0.9.0</Encoded_Library>
</track>

<track type="Video">
 <StreamOrder>0</StreamOrder>
 <ID>1</ID>
 <UniqueID>1959315852</UniqueID>
 <Format>AVC</Format>
 <Format_Profile>Main</Format_Profile>
 <Format_Level>4.1</Format_Level>
 <Format_Settings_CABAC>No</Format_Settings_CABAC>
 <Format_Settings_RefFrames>4</Format_Settings_RefFrames>
 <CodecID>V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC</CodecID>
 <Duration>7087.796</Duration>
 <BitRate>7357000</BitRate>
 <Width>1280</Width>
 <Height>544</Height>
 <Sampled_Width>1280</Sampled_Width>
 <Sampled_Height>544</Sampled_Height>
 <PixelAspectRatio>1.000</PixelAspectRatio>
 <DisplayAspectRatio>2.353</DisplayAspectRatio>
 <FrameRate_Mode>CFR</FrameRate_Mode>
 <FrameRate>23.976</FrameRate>
 <FrameCount>169937</FrameCount>
 <ColorSpace>YUV</ColorSpace>
 <ChromaSubsampling>4:2:0</ChromaSubsampling>
 <BitDepth>8</BitDepth>
 <ScanType>Progressive</ScanType>
 <Delay>0.000</Delay>
 <StreamSize>6369345470</StreamSize>
 <Encoded_Library>x264 - core 93 r1542 5b86182</Encoded_Library>
 <Encoded_Library_Name>x264</Encoded_Library_Name>
 <Encoded_Library_Version>core 93 r1542 5b86182</Encoded_Library_Version>
 <Encoded_Library_Settings>cabac=0 / ref=1 / deblock=0:-1:-1 / analyse=0:0 / me=dia / subme=0 / psy=1 / psy_rd=0.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / wpredb=1 / wpredp=0 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc=2pass / mbtree=0 / bitrate=7357 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=10 / qpmax=51 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / ip_ratio=1.40 / pb_ratio=1.30 / aq=0</Encoded_Library_Settings>
 <Default>Yes</Default>
 <Forced>No</Forced>
</track>

<track type="Audio" typeorder="1">
 <StreamOrder>1</StreamOrder>
 <ID>2</ID>
 <UniqueID>2957281200</UniqueID>
 <Format>AC-3</Format>
 <Format_Settings_Endianness>Big</Format_Settings_Endianness>
 <CodecID>A_AC3</CodecID>
 <Duration>7087.808</Duration>
 <BitRate_Mode>CBR</BitRate_Mode>
 <BitRate>640000</BitRate>
 <Channels>6</Channels>
 <ChannelPositions>Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE</ChannelPositions>
 <ChannelLayout>L C R LFE Ls Rs</ChannelLayout>
 <SamplesPerFrame>1536</SamplesPerFrame>
 <SamplingRate>48000</SamplingRate>
 <SamplingCount>340214784</SamplingCount>
 <FrameRate>31.250</FrameRate>
 <BitDepth>16</BitDepth>
 <Compression_Mode>Lossy</Compression_Mode>
 <Delay>0.000</Delay>
 <Delay_Source>Container</Delay_Source>
 <StreamSize>567024640</StreamSize>
 <StreamSize_Proportion>0.07407</StreamSize_Proportion>
 <Language>de</Language>
 <ServiceKind>CM</ServiceKind>
 <Default>Yes</Default>
 <Forced>No</Forced>
 <extra>
  <bsid>8</bsid>
  <dialnorm>-31</dialnorm>
  <dialnorm_String>-31 dB</dialnorm_String>
  <acmod>7</acmod>
  <lfeon>1</lfeon>
  <dialnorm_Average>-31</dialnorm_Average>
  <dialnorm_Average_String>-31 dB</dialnorm_Average_String>
  <dialnorm_Minimum>-31</dialnorm_Minimum>
  <dialnorm_Minimum_String>-31 dB</dialnorm_Minimum_String>
  <dialnorm_Maximum>-31</dialnorm_Maximum>
  <dialnorm_Maximum_String>-31 dB</dialnorm_Maximum_String>
  <dialnorm_Count>559</dialnorm_Count>
 </extra>
</track>

<track type="Audio" typeorder="2">
 <StreamOrder>2</StreamOrder>
 <ID>3</ID>
 <UniqueID>1226757255</UniqueID>
 <Format>AC-3</Format> 
 <Format_Settings_Endianness>Big</Format_Settings_Endianness>
 <CodecID>A_AC3</CodecID>
 <Duration>7087.808</Duration>
 <BitRate_Mode>CBR</BitRate_Mode>
 <BitRate>640000</BitRate>
 <Channels>6</Channels>
 <ChannelPositions>Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE</ChannelPositions>
 <ChannelLayout>L C R LFE Ls Rs</ChannelLayout>
 <SamplesPerFrame>1536</SamplesPerFrame>
 <SamplingRate>48000</SamplingRate>
 <SamplingCount>340214784</SamplingCount>
 <FrameRate>31.250</FrameRate>
 <BitDepth>16</BitDepth>
 <Compression_Mode>Lossy</Compression_Mode>
 <Delay>0.000</Delay>
 <Delay_Source>Container</Delay_Source>
 <StreamSize>567024640</StreamSize>
 <StreamSize_Proportion>0.07407</StreamSize_Proportion>
 <Language>en</Language>
 <ServiceKind>CM</ServiceKind>
 <Default>No</Default>
 <Forced>No</Forced>
 <extra>
  <bsid>8</bsid>
  <dialnorm>-31</dialnorm>
  <dialnorm_String>-31 dB</dialnorm_String>
  <acmod>7</acmod>
  <lfeon>1</lfeon>
  <dialnorm_Average>-31</dialnorm_Average>
  <dialnorm_Average_String>-31 dB</dialnorm_Average_String>
  <dialnorm_Minimum>-31</dialnorm_Minimum>
  <dialnorm_Minimum_String>-31 dB</dialnorm_Minimum_String>
  <dialnorm_Maximum>-31</dialnorm_Maximum>
  <dialnorm_Maximum_String>-31 dB</dialnorm_Maximum_String>
  <dialnorm_Count>556</dialnorm_Count>
 </extra>
</track>

</media>
</MediaInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing to set the namespace of your XML source with the `-N` parameter of `xmlstarlet`. So the following command should set the value as desired:

```
xmlstarlet -q ed -N mi="https://mediaarea.net/mediainfo" -u "/mi:MediaInfo/mi:media/mi:track[@type='Video']/mi:BitRate" -v "123456 Kb/s" test.xml
```

It sets the `BitRate` of the `@type='video'` `track` to "123456 Kb/s".